# Is there idiomatic pointfree way to call a function with arguments through another functions

Tags: haskell, pointfree

We have these functions

```
foo x1 x2 ... xN =

f1 x =
f2 x =
...
fN x =
```

Is there idiomatic pointfree version of this function?

```
bar x1 x2 ... xn = foo (f1 x1) (f2 x2) ... (fN xN)
```

edit

If not can we somehow generalize this function to N parameters?

```
applyF3 f f1 f2 f3 x1 x2 x3 = f (f1 x1) (f2 x2) (f3 x3)
bar = applyF3 foo f1 f2 f3
```

Comment: I think the pointful version you suggested is about as idiomatic as it gets.

Comment: For `n = 5` you'd get something like: `bar = flip flip f5 . ((flip . ((flip . ((.) .)) .)) .) . flip flip f4 . ((flip . ((.) .)) .) . flip flip f3 . ((.) .) . (. f2) . foo . f1` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really idiomatic:

```
import Control.Arrow

bar = curry . curry $ (f1 *** f2) *** f3 >>> (uncurry . uncurry $ foo)
```

Add more `curry/uncurry`s for more arguments.

The pointful version is much more clear.

Comment: Yes, although with N-ary versions of curry/uncurry like we have for (eg) zipWith and liftM, this would be reasonably clear: `bar = curry4 $ uncurry4 foo . (f1 *** f2 *** f3 *** f4)`

Comment: @amalloy I think with example of curryN uncurryN implementation you should post curryN $ uncurryN foo . (f1 *** f2 *** ... *** fN) as answer.

Comment: @amalloy Indeed. I looked for them on hackage, but surprisingly they are not in any package. They are easy to define, of course, but I wanted to stick to available combinators. Also don't forget that `uncurryN` would produce (I assume) an N-tuple, which is incompatible with `f1***...***fN` which expects nested pairs.

Comment: @chi I think this functions should have different names, something like curryPairs uncurryPairs

Answer (score 1):

If we have this set of functions

```
uncurryPairsN f (x1,(x2,...)) =  f x1 x2 ... xN
curryPairsN f x1 x2 ... xN =  f (x1, (x2, ...))
```

then

```
bar = curryPairsN $ uncurryPairsN foo . (f1 *** f2 *** ... *** fN)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Data.Function.Pointless](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointless-fun/docs/Data-Function-Pointless.html) from the package pointless-fun:

If you have

`bar x1 x2 x3 = foo (f1 x1) (f2 x2) (f3 x3)`

you can turn it into the pointless refactoring

`bar = foo ~> f1 ~> f2 ~> f3 ~> id`

The workings are described in a [blog post](http://matt.immute.net/content/pointless-fun).